# How to find closest two samples for a given time in a glTF animation

Tags: animation, search, interpolation, sampling, gltf

I'm loading animation data from a glTF file. The [glTF 2.0 spec](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0#animations) mandates that animation data is stored as two arrays of data called "input" and "output". The input array stores times, in seconds, and the output array stores sampled values for the given time.

[image]
[Image source](https://kcoley.github.io/glTF/specification/2.0/figures/gltfOverview-2.0.0a.png)

Given some time value *t* (say, 1.2 seconds like in the diagram) how do I find the two closest adjacent samples to interpolate? Is binary search the most efficient method?

#### Edit

I've found a bit of additional context. When a user suggested adding support for fixed timesteps to the glTF spec, [someone replied](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/issues/731#issuecomment-250088174):

> You can easily sample to whatever fix frame rate you need when loading the animation data. There is no need to bloat the animation size in the transmitted data.

There are also some notes in [an old Samples repository](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples-Deprecated/blob/master/samples/apps/atw/scenes/scene_gltf.h#L131) about this:

```
- All animations time-lines are based on a global time. However, an
  application can re-base the animation times and choose to play
  animations at different times.
- No support for fixed rate animations. Animations always use a time-line
  with a time for each key frame, possibly with a variable delta
  time in between key frames. To avoid a statefull animations system
  (which would be a terrible idea) an application has to look up the
  surrounding key frames from the time-line every frame. This can be
  sped up by using a binary search but for long animations with many
  hundreds of key frames this is still not cheap because it effectively
  results in random memory access. To make matters worse there may be
  a separate "animation" for every channel of a joint (scale, translation,
  rotation) with a different time-line. Some models actually store a
  different time-line per joint or channel, even though the actual
  time-lines are the same. As a result, an expensive lookup may be
  needed for every joint or even every channel, every frame. This is
  particularly silly considering many models store a time-line that
  is effectively fixed rate. Significant data preprocessing at load
  time would be required to identify all the cases that can be optimized.
```

So currently, the two potential solutions I'm aware of are:

1. Binary search each timeline for key *t* and consider the closest node(s).
2. Re-sample all timelines at load time (or in a preprocess step) with respect to a fixed dt and use a direct indexed lookup based on `t / fixed_dt`.

Would be very curious to know about any alternatives.

Comment: I'm pretty sure binary search was the intent of the authors.  I'd be curious to know if anything else is faster.

Comment: @emackey Someone also suggested I could cache the current_index and search forward/backward from that index depending on if *t* is lower or higher, which be O(1) as long as *t* was always less than or equal to the sample rate of the animation. He also suggested that if I couldn't find *t* within *n* steps, to fall back on binary search.